# JUnit testcase looks one more extra test case

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit, testcase

I am new in writing JUnit tests. I have 6 test case but when I run them it shows 7/7 passed. Also it prints an extra line when I run these test cases automatically, there is no extra print when I try them manually. It looks like there is some extra hidden case, but I am not sure. Here is my code

```
import junit.framework.TestCase;

public class ReservationManagerTest extends TestCase {
    @Test
    public void testCase1() {
        ReservationManager manager = new ReservationManager(1);
        assertFalse(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(-4, 2)));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void TestCase2() {
        ReservationManager manager = new ReservationManager(1);
        assertEquals(false, manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(200, 400)));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void TestCase3() {
        ReservationManager manager = new ReservationManager(3);
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(0, 5)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(7, 13)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(3, 9)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(5, 7)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(6, 6)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(0, 4)));
    }
    
    @Test
    void TestCase4() {
        ReservationManager manager = new ReservationManager(3);
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(1, 3)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(2, 5)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(1, 9)));
        assertFalse(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(0, 15)));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void TestCase5() {
        ReservationManager manager = new ReservationManager(3);
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(1, 3)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(0, 15)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(1, 9)));
        assertFalse(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(2, 5)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(4, 9)));
    }
    
    @Test
    public void TestCase6() {
        ReservationManager manager = new ReservationManager(2);
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(1, 3)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(0, 4)));
        assertFalse(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(2, 3)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(5, 5)));
        assertFalse(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(4, 10)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(10, 10)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(6, 7)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(8, 10)));
        assertTrue(manager.checkAvailability(new Reservation(8, 9)));
    }

}
```

Comment: Hi, 
How exactly you run those tests?

Comment: @lazylead Hi. i am working on Eclipse. I basically run with Run As --> JUnit Test

Comment: You are running an ancient version of JUnit... it looks you are using version 3.x as the class `TestCase`  was removed in junit 4. Just mentioning this as eclipse might see the class `TestCase` as an extra item in the junit report.

Comment: @Augusto as you said I changed it and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: Enjoy learning about unit testing. TDD is a wonderful and fun design technique :)